# Top 15 products, need a number to show for each one, starting with 1

Tags: php, numbers, range

I'm creating a new website, I don't want to link direct to it so I'll put spaces inbetween:
test . glow - sticks . org
I have a list of the 15 most popular products on the right hand side of the page (WHATS HOT), I would like to show a number for each one, the first being 1 and the last being 15.

I am a php noob, but despite reading about using range and foreach at the php manual site, I'm struggling to show numbers. I've found it easy to show the same range of numbers for each product block, e.g 1,2,3...15 showing 15 times, but this obviously isn't what I'm trying to do.

I probably need to give more info than I have here, so I'll past the code that I'm working with on the php include:

```
<div id="whatshot_smallblock">
<a href='/<?=str_replace(" ","-",$productname)?>.html'><img src='http://www.glow-sticks.org/images/products/<?=$productimage?>' alt='<?=$productname?>' width='66' height='66' hspace="2" vspace="2" border='0' class="radius" />
</a>
<div id="whatshot_smallblock_Txt">  
<a href='/<?=str_replace(" ","-",$productname)?>.html'><?=$productname?></a><br><div id="pink_color"><span class="content_2"><?=$minprice_dis?></span><?=$_SESSION['currsymbol']?><?=$minprice?></div></div>
<div id="bigblacknumbers"></div></div>
```

and in my objectmanager php file I can see the code relating to the whatshot section:

```
//what's hot
function whatshotids() {
    if( !isset( $this->dblink ) )
    dbconnect();

    //$sql = "SELECT COUNT(pid) AS repetitions, pid FROM gs_orderlines GROUP BY pid ORDER BY repetitions DESC LIMIT 15";
    $timenow = time();
    $checktime = ($timenow - 1814400); // 3 weeks
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(pid) AS repetitions, gs_orderlines.pid FROM gs_orderlines INNER JOIN gs_orders ON gs_orders.oid =
            gs_orderlines.oid WHERE gs_orders.datetime >= $checktime GROUP BY gs_orderlines.pid ORDER BY repetitions DESC LIMIT 15";

    $result = mysql_query( $sql, $this->dblink )
    or die( "Invalid query Line 1018" );
    $i = 0;
    $whids = array();
    while( $row = mysql_fetch_object( $result ) ) {
        ////
        $sql2 = "SELECT * from gs_inventory WHERE pid = ".$row->pid. " AND display_product='1' AND stock>0 AND canbackstock!='yes'";
        $result2 = mysql_query( $sql2, $this->dblink ); 
        if($row2 = mysql_fetch_object( $result2 )){ 
            $whids[$row->pid] = $row->repetitions;
            $i = $i + 1;
        }
    ...
    }
...
}
```

Hopefully this is enough or too much information.

Many thanks!

Comment: I dont see how the 2 pieces of code you have included work together ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seemed that the only thing I needed to do was to enter:

```
<?$counter++; echo $counter;?>
```

And it just started counting from the first iteration.

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
<?php
$i=1;
foreach($products as $product) { ?>
<div id="whatshot_smallblock">
<?php echo $i; ?><a href='/<?=str_replace(" ","-",$productname)?>.html'><img src='http://www.glow-sticks.org/images/products/<?=$productimage?>' alt='<?=$productname?>' width='66' height='66' hspace="2" vspace="2" border='0' class="radius" />
</a>
<div id="whatshot_smallblock_Txt">  
<a href='/<?=str_replace(" ","-",$productname)?>.html'><?=$productname?></a><br><div id="pink_color"><span class="content_2"><?=$minprice_dis?></span><?=$_SESSION['currsymbol']?>    <?=$minprice?></div></div>
<div id="bigblacknumbers"></div></div>
<?php 
$i++;
} ?>
```

So, basically, just loop through your products and echo $i (a number that gets +1 on each iteration)....

Comment: Hi, thanks for having a go at this, I appreciate because of my experience of probably the incorrect information it's more complicated than normal.

I have tried to use what you've said, I received a couple of errors because of unexpected this and that etc, but I managed to make it half work, except all the iterations echo just 1.

Comment: I tried to paste the code but there isn't enough space here, I uploaded it to the test page and as you can see it just shows 1 for each product box.

Comment: can you post your edited code. it seems you have missed `$i++` or you are setting `$i=1` in foreach loop statment

Comment: What Arash says, please do give us the code somewhere. The above two suggestions seem to be the case

Answer (score 1):

With the code you have included its difficult to see how you output your HTML ... the 2 pieces of code look very disconnected ...

To do what you want you could just use an incremental count in your while loop :

```
$num = 1;
while( $row = mysql_fetch_object( $result ) ) {
  echo "Product Number = " . $num;
  $num++; // increment
  // do what every else you need
}
```

The problem is - you are not outputting any code in your PHP ... if you update your question it might help

Comment: Thanks for your comment which did help me some what.